# Custom Pagination: how to navigate to specific page number from inputtext? Its not working for me!

Tags: apex, pagination

```
<apex:page controller="Pagnt" tabStyle="Applicant__c">
   <apex:form >
     <apex:panelGrid id="details" >
       <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:actionStatus id="pageStatus">
            <apex:facet name="start">
              <apex:outputPanel >
                <img src="{!$Resource.Loader}" width="80" height="20" />
              <apex:outputLabel value="Loading..."/>
              </apex:outputPanel>            
            </apex:facet>
          </apex:actionStatus>

       <apex:pageblockTable value="{!applist}" var="app">
            <apex:column value="{!app.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!app.First_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!app.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:facet name="footer">Page {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet> 

       </apex:pageblockTable>
      Go To Page &nbsp; <apex:inputText value="{!num}" size="1" />
      <apex:commandButton status="pageStatus" value="GO" action="{!Go}" rerender="details" />
       <apex:pageblockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton status="pageStatus" value="First" rerender="details" action="{!First}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
         <apex:commandButton status="pageStatus" value="Previous" rerender="details" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
         <apex:commandButton status="pageStatus" value="Next" rerender="details" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
         <apex:commandButton status="pageStatus" value="Last" rerender="details" action="{!Last}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
       </apex:pageblockButtons>

      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:panelGrid>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My APex Code

```
public with sharing class Pagnt {

    public void Go() 
    {

     x = num ;

    }

    public Integer num { get; set; }

    public Integer x {get; set;}

    public Integer getPageNumber() {

       x = offsetsize/LimitSize +1 ;

       return x;
   }

   public Integer getTotalPages() 
   {
      if (math.mod(totalRecs, Limitsize) > 0) 
      {
         return totalRecs/LimitSize + 1;

      } 
      else 
      {
         return (totalRecs/LimitSize);
      }
   }

     public integer totalRecs = 0;
     public integer OffsetSize = 0;
     public integer LimitSize= 5;

     public Pagnt()
     {
           totalRecs = [select count() from Applicant__c];


     }

     public List<Applicant__c> getapplist()
     {

           List<Applicant__C> app = Database.Query('SELECT Name, first_Name__C, Email__C  FROM Applicant__C ORDER BY createddate ASC NULLS LAST  LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize');
           System.debug('Values are ' + app);
           return app;
     }

    public void First(){

        OffsetSize = 0;
      }

    public void previous(){

        OffsetSize = OffsetSize - LimitSize;
      }

    public void next(){

        OffsetSize = OffsetSize + LimitSize;
      }

    public void Last(){

       OffsetSize = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,LimitSize);

      }
    public boolean getprev()
        {
          if(OffsetSize == 0)
          return true;
          else
          return false;
        }
    public boolean getnxt()
       {
          if((OffsetSize + LimitSize) > totalRecs)
          return true;
          else
          return false;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`OffsetSize` is the magic number in your code that handles the pagination in the querying of the `Applicant__c` objects in the method below.

```
 public List<Applicant__c> getapplist() {
       List<Applicant__C> app = Database.Query('SELECT Name, first_Name__C, Email__C  FROM Applicant__C ORDER BY createddate ASC NULLS LAST  LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize');
       System.debug('Values are ' + app);
       return app;
 }
```

So to move to a desired page you have to increase `OffsetSize` in increments of `LimitSize` to get to the correct page. Your `go` method should be something along the lines of:

```
public void go() {
    offsetSize = (limitSize * num);
}
```